# Selecting <p> within a div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to select the p tag and style it within a content class div. Here is the example HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<p> this is paragraph </p>
</div>
```

I want to select and style the p which is immediately after the  div. The p has no ID or class.

How can I select it via JavaScript?

Comment: [divElement.getElementsByTagName('p')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: That `<p>` is *not* 'after' the `<div>`.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done using `querySelector`. You did not specify minimum browser requirement.

```
var p = document.querySelector(".content p");
p.style.color = "red";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g35ec/

Answer (score 6):

if you can get access to the div, you can use

```
var ps = divObject.getElementsByTagName('p'); //ps contains all of the p elements inside your div
var p = ps[0]; //take the first element
```

Comment: my question is: i would like to select p inside div tag. and p is no id or class. how I can select p? could you explain more.. thank

Comment: @user3536919 - what browsers are you targeting? there are many options, but not all are compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector('.content p').style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: Be aware that the querySelector method isn't compatible in IE7 and below.

Comment: @Hatsjoem - And `getElementsByClassName` is not available in IE8, so `querySelector` has better support

Comment: Is it not? I had no idea about that (beyond the usual 'poor IE support').

Comment: Nope, [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) is IE9 and up only, while `querySelector` works in IE8 and above.

Comment: Even jQuery is dropping support for IE6/7 later this year, so I'd call compatibility issues from those browsers pretty irrelevant at this point.

Answer (score 1):

to style

tag use it normally as you do 
in the style tag or if you use a separate css file.
Have a look at this fiddle it might help you

http://jsfiddle.net/3uUjf/

```
p{
background-color: cyan;
```

}